# Should I exclude APK generation for 64 bit architectures?

Tags: android

Having made releases without much focus on architectures support, I have come to finally focus on it because of the size the binaries are adding to the APK. As per the documentation, Android generates APK for all architectures(ABIs), that consists of:

- armeabi
- armeabi-v7a
- arm64-v8a
- mips
- x86
- x86_64
- mips64

I have Crashlytics integrated for example that has associated .so libs for each of these architectures that is ultimately adding to the APK size.

My question is, would it be safe to support only armeabi-v7a, mips and x86 and exclude others from support?

Are these other architectures really worth the size they are adding?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Are you excluding the other devices from running your app?

Comment: @MikeBonnell : Currently, I am not excluding anything but the APK analyzer shows crashlytics related .so libs in each of these architecture directories which, as the APK analyzer shows, is adding to the APK size considerably. That's why, I was interested in excluding the architectures that might not be worth investing into.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, you can take advantage of ABI splits (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits#TOC-ABIs-Splits) to filter the appropriate architectures if necessary.